# The ordering of the field $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{R}$ has the same order

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

The field consisting of the set $\mathbb{C}$ and the **usual** +,$\times$ cannot be ordered. But we can order the set $\mathbb{C}$ by mapping it to the set $\mathbb{R}$ and defining different addition and multiplication operations satisfying the field axioms. My question is can we make an ordered field on the set $\mathbb{C}$ with some addition and multiplication operations such that the order of $\mathbb{R}$ is kept the same as the usual order? If such operations don't exist prove that they don't exist.

Comment: Do you mean without $\Bbb R$ being a subfield?

Comment: @Gae.S. I am not restricting about that. It can be a sub field or not be a sub field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordering on $\Bbb R$ can be extended to an ordering on $\Bbb R(x)$ by postulating that $x>\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ and that for any two non-zero polynomials $p,q$ the rational function $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ has the same sign as the ratio of their leading coefficients. Then you can consider a bijection $\Phi:\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R\to \Bbb R(x)\setminus\Bbb R$ and the map \begin{align}&\Psi:\Bbb C\to\Bbb R(x)\\&\Psi(u)=\begin{cases}u&\text{if }u\in\Bbb R\\ \Phi(u)&\text{if }u\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R\end{cases}\end{align}

The operations \begin{align}a+_\Psi b&=\Psi^{-1}(\Psi(a)+\Psi(b))\\ a\times_\Psi b&=\Psi^{-1}(\Psi(a)\Psi(b))\\ a\le_\Psi b&\Leftrightarrow \Psi(a)\le\Psi(b)\end{align}

accomplish what you want and $(\Bbb R,+_\Psi,\times_\Psi,\le_{\Psi})$ is an ordered subfield which is isomorphic to the usual $\Bbb R$ via the tautological map.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}(x)$ the set of all polynomials with real coeffiecients?

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy No, that would be $\Bbb R[x]$. $\Bbb R(x)$ is the field of (formal) [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function).

Comment: In the last sentence, do you mean "the usual $\mathbb{C}$"?

Comment: @NilsMatthes No, I meant $(\Bbb R,+_\Psi,\cdots)$ et cetera, but the guy edited it without me realising it.